# Finding if value is between two columns in data table

Tags: c#, linq

For the past week I have been searching for an answer to this  problem I am having and I cannot seem to find the answer.

I have written a program to run a raffle for an online game I play.  The problem I have is that I need to remove duplicates from the drawing of the main prizes (new requirement).

What I have now the database gets loaded into a DataTable and then I generate a random number and then I need to find where that random number falls between two columns in the DataTable, `TicketNumberStart` and `TicketNumberEnd`.  Here is what I am using for my LINQ right now.

```
var winner = from jnkDt in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where
    jnkDt.Field<int>("TicketNumberStart") > rndNumber &&
    jnkDt.Field<int>("TicketNumberEnd") < rndNumber
    select new
    {
        name = jnkDt.Field<string>("BuyerName")
    };
    foreach (var jnk in winner)
        tmpName = jnk.name.ToString();
```

The problem I am running into is that this returns a blank string no matter what the rndNumber is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `TicketNumberEnd` is *more than* `TicketNumberStart`, in which case your condition will *never* be true.  I suspect you need to flip the comparisons:

```
var winner = from jnkDt in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where
    jnkDt.Field<int>("TicketNumberStart") <= rndNumber &&
    jnkDt.Field<int>("TicketNumberEnd") >= rndNumber
....
```

OR

```
var winner = from jnkDt in dt.AsEnumerable()
    where
    rndNumber >= jnkDt.Field<int>("TicketNumberStart") &&
    rndNumber <= jnkDt.Field<int>("TicketNumberEnd")
```

Comment: Don't forget to use equals if the range is inclusive. Since it's very common to have an inclusive range start, you're almost sure to need <= for the TicketNumberStart test.

Comment: @D Stanley Okay thank you for the help.  That is my problem.  I guess I've been staring at the code for too long and didn't see that.